# Scrape web table to multi-dimensional array list

Tags: python, arrays

I am trying to scrape a html table into a multi-dimensional array however my results are only a single array list:

```
import requests
import lxml.html as lh
import pandas as pd
url='https://www.mscorecard.com/mscorecard/showcourse.php?cid=141521162939611337'

#Create a handle, page, to handle the contents of the website
page = requests.get(url)

#Store the contents of the website under doc
doc = lh.fromstring(page.content)

#Parse data that are stored between <tr>..</tr> of HTML
tr_elements = doc.xpath('//tr')

#Create empty list
tees=[]
yards=[]
holes=[]
col=[]
h=['2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20']
i=0
j=2

#For each row, store each first element (header) and an empty list
for t in tr_elements[1]:
   i+=1
   name=t.text_content()
#print ('%d:"%s"'%(i,name))
#print(name)
if name not in ['Hole','Par','Hcp']:
    tees.append(name)
col.append((name,[]))
print('Tees', tees)

# testing
hx, tx = (18,(len(tees)))
for i in range(tx):
  col = []
  for x in h:
    #print(x,i+3,i)
    for t in (tr_elements[int(x)]):
        name=t.text_content()
        holes.append(name)
    yards.append(holes[i])
print(yards)
```

Below is the result from code above:

```
Tees ['Black', 'Blue', 'White', 'Red (L)']

['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '451', '451', '451', '451', '451', '451', '451', '451', '451', '451', '451', '451', '451', '451', '451', '451', '451', '451']
```

The output should read:

```
[['451','371','200','346','442','419','241','385','541','561','387','308','456','180','584','181','405','165'],['401','354','164','298','408','398','210','319','511','538','372','288','448','149','560','160','379','148'],['346','326','152','291','363','388','200','260','415','511','361','255','386','138','548','149','330','111'],['251','277','117','261','325','354','166','225','355','439','278','187','325','94','489','111','269','90]]
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_html(url)[0]

def get_value(index):
    return list(np.concatenate([df.iloc[:,index][2:11].to_numpy(), df.iloc[:,index][12:21].to_numpy()]))

res = []
for i in range(3,7):
    res.append(get_value(i))
```

Comment: Awesome! That worked and with a lot less code than I was using. Thanks